# Good practices angular reactive forms, edit an object

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have been learning to use reactive forms in angular 7 but have some trouble understanding how to use it.

Example:

```
Export class Person {
    id: string, 
    name: string
}

Export class myFormComponent implememts OnInit {

    personForm: FormGroup;
    @Input()
    person: Person;

    Constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {} 

    NgOnInit() {
       this.personForm = this.fb.group({
          name: [this.person.name, [Validators.required]]
       });
    } 
}

<form [formGroup]="personForm" >
    <input formControlName="name" >
</form>
```

My component takes in entry a person object to edit, but seeing as we are not using `([ngModel])` the values are not modified inside the person model that is passed in the parameters of the component.

Now I know we can just read the values of the form on submit and affect the changes to the properties one by one or by affecting all form values but that would mean we are missing the id attribute (as we don't use it in the form).

I just want to know what the best practice is in this type of scenario.

Comment: what is `this.name` shouldn't it be `this.person.name`?

Comment: Yes sorry its supposed to take the person name as default value. Had to write this on a smartphone as the site is blocked by my company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The principles of reactive forms and template driven forms are very different : you can't really compare them and expect the same things from both.

[In the documentation, under "Key differences"](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview#key-differences), you will see that they both have very different purposes.

To sum it up, template driven **updates the model in a direct way**, while reactive forms **copy the model and updates the copy of the model**.

If you want to update your model with reactive forms, you do it on demand (for instance, right before making an HTTP call).

They both have their advantages and drawbacks, and you should use them accordingly. They're **complementary**, not **competing**.

Comment: I see. I saw reactive controls being a lot more flexible and cleaner to implement so i went with that. So as best practice i simply add the id attribute to the form (and not use it in the template) so i can assign all form attributes to the person model, or do i take the person object and modify all attributes one by one?

Comment: @lolplayer101 well an ID should not be modified, but if you want to modify it, then yes, you will have to add it to your form.

Comment: maybe i was unclear, thats the thing, i do not want modify it. I don't even wanna display it. I am wondering if i should assign all the individual form control values to my person model or add id to the personForm in order to pass all values in one go from personForm to my person model on submit.

Comment: you can use `builder.group(this.person)` and it will create all fields at once (you do not need to hard code them). Your ID will be stored in `form.value`, but as long as you don't create an `input formControlName="id"`, it will never show and no lambda user will be able to modify it. You can also manually disable it once the form has been created, or even at creation !

Comment: That is exactely what i need thanks, weird that its not written anywhere in their guides. Last question, how do i add the validators now?

Comment: Depends, if you do `builder.group(this.person)` you have to call `form.get(fieldName).setValidators([validators])`. Otherwise, you can use `builder.group({ name: ['', [validators]] })`

Comment: @trichteiche Thats it! Thank you so much. I have been stuck on this all morning. At least i learnedit the hard way. Thanks again and have a great day.

Comment: No problem, then again [the documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl) has everything you need !